# jQuery Tabs, object has no method 'tabs' ASP MVC3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs, asp.net-mvc

As title says.

I'm trying to use jQuery Tabs control for my application, yet I get no tabs just listed headers with all the content rendered below.

Here's html code for view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
@ViewBag.Sad

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Zakupione</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Niezakupione</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_BoughtReport"); }
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_NonBoughtReport"); }
    </div>
</div>
```

I checked console and all I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs' Raport:43
(anonymous function) Raport:43
f.Callbacks.o jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
```

Comment: does your jquery-ui custom file include tabs ? are your js files being loaded correctly ?

Comment: use view source on the page and check that the links to the js files are correct

Comment: did you include the tabs widget when creating your custon jquery ui ?

Comment: @the_ajp/helmus, downloaded everything jquery ui offered, it's set by default.

@ftom2/helmus, yes files are loaded properly and are correct.